# Detect the newest file and pass it to a process

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Detect the newest file in a specific folder and pass it as an argument to another process. The first argument to your program will be the folder, and the second argument will be the full path to the process.

Please specify the platform(s) your code works on.

## Examples

### Windows

```
newestfile "C:\Public_domain_movies\" "C:\Mplayer\mplayer.exe"
```

### Linux

```
./newestfile /home/user /bin/ls
```

Comment: @Geobits I expect *the most recent timestamp no matter what*, I removed the misleading part.

Comment: Actually I think it could have added a very interesting twist to have to figure out when the program was last run.

Comment: @Ventero Yes, no recursive scanning just the specified folder

Comment: The most recently *modified* file or the most recently *created* file?

Comment: @Joey 
The most recently modified

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Zsh - 15

Only tested on Linux, but it should work on other platforms too.

```
$2 $1/*(.om[1])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Windows, PowerShell, 35

```
&$args[1](ls $args[0]|sort *w*)[-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Linux, Ruby, 52 characters

```ruby
exec$*[1],Dir[$*[0]+"/*"].sort_by{|a|test(?M,a)}[-1]
```

I'm not sure if I undestood the specifications correctly, so if this doesn't work as intended, please let me know. I only tested this on Linux, but *in  theory* it should run on Windows, too.

Answer (score 2):

### linux - bash+sed - 18 bytes

```
$2 `ls -t $1|sed q`
```

Does not work if the arguments contain blanks.

Answer (score 1):

### Windows, cmd, 54

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir/b/o-d %1')do %2 %%A&exit
```

Caveats:

- Closes the current shell session
- Will consider directories (as do most other solutions)

Comment: You don't need the options string `"delims="`

Comment: Well, have fun with file names with spaces, then.

Comment: This doesn't work if the file has spaces in it

Comment: What if you add `/x` parameter for short names? `FOOBAR~1.TXT`

Comment: @nderscore: Not every file has to have a short name.